# Sitecore Commerce Authoring does not start

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am trying to install the Sitecore Commerce 9.2 solution locally by porting wwwroot folders, databases, certificates from a server where it works fine on and installing them on top of my clean instance. I have a problem with my commerce authoring role. When bizfix or web interface try to address it the requests are pending and there's no response.
If I go to CommerceAuthoring folder and try to launch Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe I get `Loading entity from file:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring\wwwroot\Bootstrap\Global.json` message and it does not progress further. There are no logs generated for CommerceAuthoring instance as well at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceAuthoring\wwwroot\logs`.
The names in config files, thumbprints, iis bindings and certificates seem to be all correct for the instance. Do you maybe have an advice on what else I might check/try to launch it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't update the SQL db connection details for the folders I moved in:

```
\wwwroot\bootstrap\Global.json
\wwwroot\data\Environments\Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json
```